# How to use more Contact Form templates?

Tags: magento2, contact-form

I use this for displaying a contact form on the website:

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

But there I would like to edit this form for different purposes and have multiple templates that I can use on different pages. When copying the `module-contact/view/templates/form.php` to a new `form2.php` and changing the code according to  {{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form2.phtml"}}, it does not display on the page. Do you know why?

Thanks,
Valentin

Comment: Add your code for more detail of error.

Comment: @DharmendraJadav did it

Comment: Try to override form.phtml in your theme or in your module and check after that.

Comment: See this https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-configure-contacts-email-address-magento-2.html it's helpful to  you for override the form.phtml file in your theme.

Comment: That is absolutely not related to what I was asking @DharmendraJadav